# Cannot find module app.module

Tags: angular, iis

I just start to learn Angular 2 and I have created an Angular 2 app with Angular2VisualStudioTemplate template.

I've *Publish* the app in Visual Studio and copy the production folder to an IIS Server. To enter the website the URL address would be something like *serverIp/myApp* so I've had to do some modifications to `index.html` and `systemjs.config.js` files in order to make the browser could find files like `main.js`, `/node_modules/`, `systemjs.config.js`..

Now when I try to access to the app, I get the next error in Chrome Inspector saying that `app.module` couldn't be found:

```
GET http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/myApp/app/app.module 404 (Not Found)
ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/myApp/app/app.module
E……}
```

The app folder structure is as follows:

```
wwwroot
|__myApp
|_____app
|_____index.html
|_____web.config
|_____...
```

I've modified the line:

`var app_module_1 = require("app.module");` to:

`var app_module_1 = require("/myApp/app/app.module")`;

located in `main.js` (inside `app` folder). Because it seems like the error comes from that file, but I didn't have lucky..

Comment: Hello, would you mind having a look at angular-cli? It is a command line tool that creates angular projects with best practices and from there you can deploy to IIS.

Comment: @GerardoTarragona  I agree with ashley `angular-cli` is easier to use and manage everything for you. its easy for a beginner to use

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya I know it's the best option when using Angular, I've used it a little bit when I was following the *heroes tutorial* from the official Angular website. But right now it's not up to me migrating the hole project to cli.. I'm gonna give it a try anyway

Comment: I just created the whole new project with angular-cli and did the deployment to the IIS web server. Now the problem is that deep linking is not working.. I've added a URL Rule to IIS with no lucky..